# Integration testing behaviour of the network. What to assert having two instances running in separate threads?

Tags: c#, integration-testing, xunit

I've created an app that can connect to its other instances on Internet and exchange some information with them. Before releasing any updates to my app, I need to be sure that apps are able to correctly establish connection with each other.

The problem is: by creating an instance of app, I'm just starting "listener" that waits for incoming network requests. `TcpConnectionsManager` is performing some "handshake", sends some info about itself, runs some initialization operations. Being in testing function, I'm not in control of what is being sent and I'm not aware of what comes from simulated network.

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task ConnectionCorrectlyEstablished()
{

    TcpConnectionsManager _hostA = new TcpConnectionsManager(_logger1);
    TcpConnectionsManager _hostB = new TcpConnectionsManager(_logger2);

    _hostA.SetupListener(13101);
    await _hostB.SetupConnectionAsync(IPAddress.Loopback, 13101);

    // what to assert here?
}
```

So in this case, I'm not receiving any "result" that can be passed to some "Assert" method in order to check if it's correct. I also cannot use try/catch block to check for errors as this function ends before `_hostA` and `_hostB` finish exchanging information in their own threads. Are there any other ways I could integration test such code?

Comment: Does `TcpConnectionManager` write some logs via `logger` instance you passing to it's constructor?

Comment: @Fabio: yes it does

Comment: So, you can check that expected logs have been written